# Firebase Swiftui not saving fetched data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am trying to fetch a userID key from firebase. The code is initiated in a .OnAppear and the data is fetched. If I try to print self.appUserId inside docRef it prints out correctly. If I print it at the end like in the code below the variable is empty. appUserID is declared as:

@State private var appUserId = ""

Can someone explain how I can fetch this firebase data and save it to a string

```
.onAppear{
        let userName = user?.email ?? ""
        let docRef = db.collection("SUBSCRIBE").document(userName)
        
        docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                //Setting Values
                let data = document.data()
                
                self.appUserId = data?["AppUserId"] as? String ?? ""
                
                
            } else {
                print("Document does not exist")
            }
        }
        
        print(self.appUserId)
    }
```

Comment: You are using asynchronous code and expecting synchronous results the inside of get document runs after the second print statement.

Comment: in other words, put your `print(self.appUserId)` just after `self.appUserId = data?["AppUserId"] as? String ?? ""`